# '-2147467259 (80004005)' with SQL SELECT string that otherwise works

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have a SELECT statement that works when it is within the VBA code, but not when it is the contents of a cell. Here is the working SQL:

```
SELECT Contacts.[Last Name], Contacts.[First Name], Contacts.[E-Mail],    Contacts.[Project, Org, Team]
FROM Contacts 
WHERE (((Contacts.[Project, Org, Team]) Like ""Team%"") AND ((Contacts.[Active?])=Yes)) 
ORDER BY Contacts.[Last Name];
```

And the connection string is the following (for both the working and non-working scripts):

```
ConnectString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
"DATABASE=" & SharepointURL & ";" & _
"LIST=" & ListID & ";"
```

If I put the SELECT statement text into a cell that is formatted as text, along with the double quotes, I get a syntax error ('-2147217900 (80040e14)') when trying to use it. Here are the statements I have to use it:

```
myQuery = Range("Project1Query").Value
ReviewersData.Open myQuery, ReviewersConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

If I change the double quotes to single quotes, the query looks like the following:

```
SELECT Contacts.[Last Name], Contacts.[First Name], Contacts.[E-Mail], Contacts.[Project, Org, Team] 
FROM Contacts 
WHERE (((Contacts.[Project, Org, Team]) like "Team%") AND ((Contacts.[Active?])=Yes)) 
ORDER BY Contacts.[Last Name];
```

And I get a cannot connect error ('-2147467259 (80004005)').

Any ideas as to how I can adjust the syntax of the SQL query? Recall, I can both connect and use the query when the SELECT statement is within the VBA. Just doesn't work when the statement is in a cell.

Answer (score 1):

It must be 'Team%' not “Team%“.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, it still has the "cannot connect" error.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the repeated double quotes in `Like ""Team%""` is to indicate to the VBA compiler that you want to include literal double quote characters in your string. The resulting string only contains individual double quote characters instead of repeated ones. This could be verified by running this code:

```
MsgBox "Like ""Team%"""
```

which results in this output:

[image: An Excel message box showing the phrase: Like Team% with the Team% part enclosed in double quotes]

The VBA compiler interprets the text of VBA macros - it turns the text of the macros into programs that can run. The compiler only deals with the text entered directly into the VBA editor. It doesn't care about text that the macro deals with at runtime - e.g. from user input, text files, Excel cell values - even if that text gets read into a VBA variable at some point.

Putting the SQL query text directly into an Excel cell bypasses the VBA compiler and its way of interpreting repeated double quotes. If you copy and paste `Like ""Team%""` into an Excel cell formatted as text and then MsgBox that cell's value, you will get this result:

[image: An Excel message box showing the phrase: Like Team% with the Team% part enclosed in repeated double quotes - two double quotes before the text and two double quotes after the text]

So putting the query directly in an Excel cell is causing extra double quote characters to be included because the query is formatted as if it will be interpreted by the VBA compiler but the cell value isn't interpreted in that way.

To make the query work with the text stored in an Excel cell, simply replace any repeated double quote characters in the query string with individual double quote characters: `Like "Team%"`

You could also use single quote characters instead of double quote characters but again there is no need to repeat the characters: `Like 'Team%'`

Another alternative is to set the cell value from VBA as this will cause the repeated double quotes to be interpreted by the VBA compiler (because the text value is now directly in the VBA editor as part of a macro) before the cell value is set: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Like ""Team%"""`

---

*edit:* if the query still works when it's within the VBA code, like this:

```
myQuery = "SELECT Contacts.[Last Name], Contacts.[First Name], Contacts.[E-Mail],    Contacts.[Project, Org, Team] " & _
    "FROM Contacts " & _
    "WHERE (((Contacts.[Project, Org, Team]) Like ""Team%"") AND ((Contacts.[Active?])=Yes)) " & _
    "ORDER BY Contacts.[Last Name];"
ReviewersData.Open myQuery, ReviewersConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

then try this version instead:

```
Range("Project1Query").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("Project1Query").Value = "SELECT Contacts.[Last Name], Contacts.[First Name], Contacts.[E-Mail],    Contacts.[Project, Org, Team] " & _
    "FROM Contacts " & _
    "WHERE (((Contacts.[Project, Org, Team]) Like ""Team%"") AND ((Contacts.[Active?])=Yes)) " & _
    "ORDER BY Contacts.[Last Name];"
myQuery = Range("Project1Query").Value
ReviewersData.Open myQuery, ReviewersConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

Setting the number format of a range to "@" specifies that the range should be formatted as text.

If this works then there must have previously been an error with how the cell value was entered

Comment: thanks. So I seem to have gotten away from the syntax error by using the `Like "Team%"` convention. But now I get a "cannot connect" error. Any thoughts as to why it would no longer be able to connect when the SQL string has been pulled from a cell?

Comment: I did try the Like 'Team%' convention and now I have an ISAM error. Since I've had to repair the excel installation, it might have messed up reference libraries. Do you recall what libraries are needed?

Comment: The only library you need should be "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library". If that isn't shown on the list of available references then search for `msado28.tlb` which is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado` on my machine

Comment: thanks for the hint on the library. I got my excel repaired and now I'm back to the "cannot connect" error.

Answer (score 0):

I think  like 'Team%'  is right.  alsoe if yes  is text,it is to be converted to 'YES' .